# Finding duplicates within strings

Tags: javascript, python, excel

I have been handed a project at work where I need to find duplicate pairings from multiple rows within a dataset. While the data set is much larger, the main portion revolves around the date of a training, the location of a training, and the names of the trainers. So every row of data has a date, a location, and then a comma separated list of names:

```
Date    Location       Names
1/13/2014   Seattle    A, B, D
1/16/2014   Dallas     C, D, E
1/20/2014   New York   A, D
1/23/2014   Dallas     C, E
1/27/2014   Seattle    B, D
1/30/2014   Houston    C, A, F
2/3/2014    Washington DC   D, A, F
2/6/2014    Phoenix    B, E
2/10/2014   Seattle    C, B
2/13/2014   Miami      A, B, E
2/17/2014   Miami      C, D 
2/20/2014   New York   B, E, F
2/24/2014   Houston    A, B, F
```

My goal is to be able to find rows with similar pairings of names. One example would be to know that A & B were in paired in Seattle on 1/13, Miami on 2/13, and Houston on 2/24, even though the third name is different in each occurrence.  So instead of just simply finding duplicates among the entire string of names, I would also like to find pairings among partial segments of the “Names” column.

Is this possible to do within Excel or would I need to use a programming language to accomplish the task?

While I can manually do this, it represents a lot of time that could be used towards other things. If there was a way that I could automate this it would make this portion of my task a lot simpler.

Thank you in advance for any assistance or advice on a way forward.

Comment: javascript and python tags are not relevant here.

Comment: My advice is repost your question on [SuperUser](http://superuser.com/) because it's inappropriate for this forum.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do it with VBA.  The solution below assumes

- Your data is on the active sheet in columns A:C
- You results will be output in columns E:G
- The output will be a list sorted by pairs, and then by dates, so you can easily see where pairs repeated.
- The routine assumes no more than three trainers at a time, but could be modified add more possible combinations.
- Cities with just a single trainer will be ignored.

The routine uses a Class module to gather the information, and two Collections to process the data.  It also makes use of the feature that collections will not allow addition of two items with the same key.

### Class Module

> Rename the Class Module:   <kbd>cPairs</kbd>

---

```
Option Explicit
Private pTrainer1 As String
Private pTrainer2 As String
Private pCity As String
Private pDT As Date
Public Property Get Trainer1() As String
    Trainer1 = pTrainer1
End Property
Public Property Let Trainer1(Value As String)
        pTrainer1 = Value
End Property
Public Property Get Trainer2() As String
    Trainer2 = pTrainer2
End Property
Public Property Let Trainer2(Value As String)
    pTrainer2 = Value
End Property
Public Property Get City() As String
    City = pCity
End Property
Public Property Let City(Value As String)
    pCity = Value
End Property

Public Property Get DT() As Date
    DT = pDT
End Property
Public Property Let DT(Value As Date)
    pDT = Value
End Property
```

---

### Regular Module

---

```
Option Explicit
Option Compare Text
Public cP As cPairs, colP As Collection
Public colCityPairs As Collection
Public vSrc As Variant
Public vRes() As Variant
Public rRes As Range
Public I As Long, J As Long
Public V As Variant
Public sKey As String

Sub FindPairs()
vSrc = Range("A1", Cells(Rows.Count, "C").End(xlUp))
Set colP = New Collection
Set colCityPairs = New Collection

'Collect Pairs
For I = 2 To UBound(vSrc)
    V = Split(Replace(vSrc(I, 3), " ", ""), ",")

    If UBound(V) >= 1 Then
        'sort the pairs
        SingleBubbleSort V

    Select Case UBound(V)
        Case 1
            AddPairs V(0), V(1)

        Case 2
            AddPairs V(0), V(1)
            AddPairs V(0), V(2)
            AddPairs V(1), V(2)
    End Select
    End If
Next I

ReDim vRes(0 To colCityPairs.Count, 1 To 3)
    vRes(0, 1) = "Date"
    vRes(0, 2) = "Location"
    vRes(0, 3) = "Pairs"

For I = 1 To colCityPairs.Count
    With colCityPairs(I)
        vRes(I, 1) = .DT
        vRes(I, 2) = .City
        vRes(I, 3) = .Trainer1 & ", " & .Trainer2
    End With
Next I

Set rRes = Range("E1").Resize(UBound(vRes, 1) + 1, UBound(vRes, 2))
With rRes
    .EntireColumn.Clear
    .Value = vRes
    With .Rows(1)
        .HorizontalAlignment = xlCenter
        .Font.Bold = True
    End With

    .Sort key1:=.Columns(3), order1:=xlAscending, key2:=.Columns(1), order2:=xlAscending, _
            Header:=xlYes
    .EntireColumn.AutoFit

    V = VBA.Array(vbYellow, vbGreen)
    J = 0
    For I = 2 To rRes.Rows.Count
        If rRes(I, 3) = rRes(I - 1, 3) Then
            .Rows(I).Interior.Color = .Rows(I - 1).Interior.Color
        Else
            J = J + 1
            .Rows(I).Interior.Color = V(J Mod 2)
        End If
    Next I
End With
End Sub

Sub AddPairs(T1, T2)

Set cP = New cPairs
With cP
    .Trainer1 = T1
    .Trainer2 = T2
    .City = vSrc(I, 2)
    .DT = vSrc(I, 1)
    sKey = .Trainer1 & "|" & .Trainer2

    On Error Resume Next

    colP.Add cP, sKey
    If Err.Number = 457 Then
        Err.Clear
        colCityPairs.Add colP(sKey), sKey & "|" & colP(sKey).DT & "|" & colP(sKey).City
        colCityPairs.Add cP, sKey & "|" & .DT & "|" & .City
    Else
        If Err.Number <> 0 Then Stop
    End If

    On Error GoTo 0

End With

End Sub

Sub SingleBubbleSort(TempArray As Variant)
'copied directly from support.microsoft.com
    Dim Temp As Variant
    Dim I As Integer
    Dim NoExchanges As Integer

    ' Loop until no more "exchanges" are made.
    Do
        NoExchanges = True

        ' Loop through each element in the array.
        For I = LBound(TempArray) To UBound(TempArray) - 1

            ' If the element is greater than the element
            ' following it, exchange the two elements.
            If TempArray(I) > TempArray(I + 1) Then
                NoExchanges = False
                Temp = TempArray(I)
                TempArray(I) = TempArray(I + 1)
                TempArray(I + 1) = Temp
            End If
        Next I
    Loop While Not (NoExchanges)
End Sub
```

[image: Results using Your Data]

Answer (score 0):

Ok. I got bored and did this whole thing in Python code. I assume you are familiar with the language; however, you should be able to get the following piece of code to work on any computer with Python installed.

I have made a few assumptions. For instance, I have used your example input as definite input.

A few things which will mess up the program:

- Not entering with case sensitivity. Beware of capital letters etc.
- Having a inputfile which has the following row: "Date    Location       Names". Just remove and keep straight facts in the file. I got lazy and do not bother adjusting this.
- A ton of other small stuff. Just do what the program asks you to do and dont enter funky input.

About program:

Revolves around using a dictionary with person names as keys. The values in the dictionary is a set with tuples containing the places they've been during what date. By then comparing these sets and getting the intersection, we can find the answer.

Kinda messy since I took this as Python practice. Have not coded in Python for a while and I got a thrill out of doing it all without utilizing objects. Just follow the "instructions" and keep the inputfile, which stores all information, in the same folder as the piece of code are running.

As a side note, you might want to check that the program yields correct output.

If you have any questions, feel free to contact me.

```
def readWord(line, stringIndex):
    word = ""
    while(line[stringIndex] != " "):
        word += line[stringIndex]
        stringIndex += 1
    return word, stringIndex

def removeSpacing(line, stringIndex):
    while(line[stringIndex] == " "):
        stringIndex += 1
    return stringIndex

def readPeople(line, stringIndex):
    lineSize = len(line)
    people = []
    while(stringIndex < lineSize):
        people.append(line[stringIndex])
        stringIndex += 3
    return people


def readLine(travels, line):
    stringIndex = 0

    date, stringIndex = readWord(line, stringIndex)
    stringIndex = removeSpacing(line, stringIndex)
    location, stringIndex = readWord(line, stringIndex)
    stringIndex = removeSpacing(line, stringIndex)
    people = readPeople(line, stringIndex)

    for person in people:
        if(person not in travels.keys()):
            travels[person] = set()
        travels[person].add((date, location))

    return travels


def main():

    f = open(input("Enter filename (must be in same folder as this program code. For instance, name could be: testDocument.txt\n\n"))
    travels = dict()
    for line in f:
        travels = readLine(travels, line)
    print("\n\n\n\n PROGRAM RUNNING \n \n")
    while(True):
        persons = []
        userInput = "empty"
        while(userInput):
            userInput = input("Enter person name (Type Enter to finish typing names): ")
            if(userInput):
                persons.append(userInput)
        output = travels[persons[0]]
        for person in persons[1:]:
            output = output.intersection(travels[person])
        print("")
        for hit in output:
            print(hit)
        print("\nFINISHED WITH ONE RUN. STARTING NEW ONE\n")
```